# Angular Express js boton crear resultado

Tags: javascript, angular, express

Hola buenas tengo un problema ya hice el endpoint para el backend y comunique el front end con el back end con el https , ademas de que ya la variable resultado esta  tomando esa información pero lo que me falta hacer es que el boton de cargar resultado cuando le haga click lo muestre en pantalla.

cualquier otra informacion que necesiten tengo el github o si no les contesto.

HTML app.component

```
<section class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m6">
      <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
        <div class="card-content white-text">
          <span class="card-title"> Resultado </span>
          <p> {{ resultado }} </p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-action">
          <a href="javascript:;"> Cargar resultado </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

app.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    numberBet() {
        return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/bet', {});
    }


}
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AppService } from './app.services';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'frontend';
  dateYear: number = new Date().getFullYear();
  resultado: string = "" ;


  constructor(public services: AppService){
    this.services.numberBet().subscribe((res: any) => {
      console.log(this.resultado = res.bet);
    }
    );
  }


}
```

express js back end

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(cors());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Welcome to backend!');
});

app.post('/bet', (req, res) => {
  res.json({
     bet: parseInt(Math.random() * (99 - 10) + 20)
  
   });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

Comment: Hola amigo y cual es el problema?

Comment: no se como hacer para que el boton cargar resultado tire el resultado

Comment: y que has intentado para lograr ese objetivo?

Comment: nada Gracias bro lo resolvi por fin BROOOOOOO que alegria ya me tenia 5 horas con la cabeza explotada , solamente hice un public y agrege una variable al <a> Gracias igual amigo no queria la solucion si no una pista recien me hice la cuenta porque ya andaba desesperado

Comment: en ese caro te recomiendo agregar la respuesta a tu propia pregunta y luego marcarla como resuelta, claro sigue las normas del sitio, eso da reputacione.